# Java variable temp is already defined in method Man_w_t(java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>)

Tags: java, arraylist

I looking for help with a problem I want to use the name of ArrayList from string any suggestion on how to repair this error :)
I link my code fragment

```
String temp = lista_Prac.get(num-1);
ArrayList<String>  temp = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: and only two temp i want use value from string to name Arraylist :)

Comment: easy way would be to rename variable `temp` to something else, like `anotherTemp`

Comment: no work bro :( or I'm stupid

Comment: 'String temp' declares a variable named 'temp'.  'ArrayList<> temp' declares a variable named 'temp'.  Surely you can see that the name 'temp' is now ambiguous?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to declare two variables with the same name in Java. Might work for two people inside a house to be named John and John but unfortunately not in java.

The only solution here would be to rename one or the other variable into something other than temp. If you have already tried this, what error are you facing ?